# How to define a json-lines response in OpenAPI?

Tags: json, swagger, openapi, mojolicious, jsonlines

Is there a way to describe a [json-lines](https://jsonlines.org/) with OpenAPI?

Besides the fact that there seems to be no MIME type for it yet, I'm wondering if it's possible to describe such a response.

In theory my response could be an array of objects, but I received the question whether or not I could deliver as json-lines, meaning: just the objects, one per line.

Since I'm using OpenAPI to describe my API I'm puzzled as how to describe this response. I could simply define the response as being of type "string", but this is not very helpful for readers of my API spec.

Comment: You might get a better answer by posting this in the OpenAPI Specification repo: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions

Comment: Unfortunately the responses there are fewer than here…

Comment: I suspect it would be just `type: string` because it doesn't have a registered MIME type and it's not vanilla JSON. But it would be nice to have a confirmation from OpenAPI maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a well-defined way to do this, given that there's no official MIME type of json-lines, and no clear way to document a schema in OpenAPI that consists of a line-delimited list of records.

When I've documented APIs like this, I've either used `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-ndjson` as the MIME type, and then specified in the API description that the schema definition applies to each record in the request / response.